# Event listeners not working in laravel-livewire 3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I am currently debugging an event that I have dispatched to be listened to where once the event is dispatched other components can listen and emit the event. Here is my code

**CreatePost.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Attributes\Rule;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Post;

class CreatePost extends Component
{
    #[Rule('required')]
    #[Rule('min:5')]
    public $title;

    #[Rule('required')]
    #[Rule('min:10')]
    public $content;

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $post = Post::create([
            'title' => $this->title,
            'content' => $this->content,
        ]);

        $this->dispatch('post-created', title: $post->title);
        
        return redirect()->to('/posts')
            ->with('status', 'Post created!');
    }
}
```

and **ShowPost Component**

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use App\Models\Post;

class ShowPosts extends Component
{
    public $posts;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->posts = Post::all();
    }

    #[On('post-created')] 
    public function refreshPosts($title)
    { 
        $this->posts = Post::all();

        session()->flash('message', 'A new post was created:' . $title);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.show-posts');
    }
}
```

This component will listen to the CreatePost component and display the event but it's not shown when I create a new post here

show-posts.blade.php

```
<div>
    <h1>All Posts</h1>
    @if (session()->has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('message') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div>
            <h3>{{ $post->title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ $post->content }}</p>
            <livewire:show-comments :postId="$post->id" :key="$post->id"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
   
</div>
```

Comment: do `dd(session()->all())`

Comment: Also put `\Log::debhg('it is listening')` in `refreshPosts($title)` function to check if this function is really listening

Comment: @ZainFarooq it is not listening at all.

Comment: I don't think the event will have the time to work since you're redirecting the user right after.

Comment: I think the issue here may be your use of session.  Try setting a public field in your livewire component when you recieve the event and that should update your client side html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it by removing

```
 return redirect()->to('/posts')
            ->with('status', 'Post created!');
```

from CreatePost component

As I discovered livewire components must be on the same page for event listeners to work. The above code was redirecting the user to ShowPost page where the event listener could not be displayed since they were different pages.

But I have placed them on the same page like this...

```
 <title>{{ $title ?? 'Page Title' }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>          
          @livewire('create-post')
          @livewire('show-posts')
          @livewireScripts
    </body>
</html>
```

And my CreatePost looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Attributes\Rule;
use Livewire\Component;
use App\Models\Post;

class CreatePost extends Component
{
    #[Rule('required')]
    #[Rule('min:5')]
    public $title;

    #[Rule('required')]
    #[Rule('min:10')]
    public $content;

    public function updated($propertyName)
    {
        $this->validateOnly($propertyName);
    }

    public function save()
    {
        $this->validate();

        $post = Post::create([
            'title' => $this->title,
            'content' => $this->content,
        ]);

        $this->dispatch('post-created', ['title' => $post->title]);

        session()->flash('message', 'Post created!');
    }
}
```

And my ShowPost

```
<?php

namespace App\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\Attributes\On;
use App\Models\Post;

class ShowPosts extends Component
{  
    public $posts;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->posts = Post::all();
    }

    #[On('post-created')] 
    public function refreshPosts($data)
    {
        $title = $data['title']; 
    
        $this->posts = Post::all();
    
        session()->flash('message', 'A new post was created: ' . $title);
    }
    
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.show-posts');
    }
}
```

Lastly
show-posts.blade.php

```
<div>
    <h1>All Posts</h1>
    @if (session()->has('message'))
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            {{ session('message') }}
        </div>
    @endif
    @foreach($posts as $post)
        <div>
            <h3>{{ $post->title }}</h3>
            <p>{{ $post->content }}</p>
            <livewire:show-comments :postId="$post->id" :key="$post->id"/>
        </div>
    @endforeach
   
</div>
```